# Laravel - Blade; How to cycle through nested json objects with different top level titles, in a @foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Most languages let you cycle through a json object, getting the top level names.

```
object = {
    "a": {"inner json objects"},
    "b" : {"..."},
    "C" : {"..."}
}
```

For example in html.twig the syntax is as such:

```
{% for title, section  in object %}
  // do something with title (ie. a, b, c)
  // do something (cycle through) with section(ie. '...')
{% endfor %}
```

I want to do the equivalent in blade.php.

I have tried multiple variations on the blade syntax, such as

```
@foreach(json_encode($object) as $title)
```

but I can't figure it out, and I can't find any appropriate documentation online.
[This stackoverflow question is the closest I could find.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751535/multiple-variable-pass-in-one-foreach-loop-in-laravel-blade/53752064), but it isn't quite appropriate as it doesn't stipulate the object I'm grabbing from

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what does "features" mean? elements, properties?

Comment: Hi,I've editted the question for a bit more clarity. thanks

Comment: `foreach ($thing as $key => $value)` ?   and why would you be calling `json_encode` that turns something into a string ... the PHP manual is your friend

Comment: YES! thank you, that worked.

@foreach($theme as $title => $section)

Comment: write it up as an answer there, and I'll accept/ upvote it  if you want. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably just looking for the `foreach` syntax that allows you to define the key name as well:

```
foreach ($something as $key => $value)
```

Everything inside the `(...)` in the Blade `@foreach(...)` directive is just regular PHP, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

[Two arrays in foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480803/two-arrays-in-foreach-loop)

This should answer your question. You'll need to combine them since PHP foreach loops only loop one array at a time.

You could do a nested loop as well if that works for your needs.

Comment: You can't have an object or array as a key.